# CDMA 4G network connectivity

Tags: android

My app can not connect to 4G on HTC EV0 device. How app can access network through CDMA 4G?

Comment: Without more specific details this sounds like a hardware/carrier problem rather than a programming problem.

Comment: "CDMA 4G" is not a thing.  CDMA and 4G (as those terms are used when referring to cell network types) are two different technologies.

Answer (score 0):

Your application cannot choose what network the carrier is using. Whatever wireless network the device has is how your application will access Internet services. If you're trying to restrict your application to specific carriers (and their network), you can do this when you publish it to Android Market. Just select the country link and underneath it will expose the carriers available. By checking off the specific carriers your app will only be visible to users on those carriers. Although even carriers can have more than one network in play at any one time. Something tells me this isn't the answer you were looking for, but I thought it might help someone.